# python the multiple largest numbers in a list

Tags: python

```
import random as rd

ListNumbers1 = []
List1 = []


for j in range(1000):
    ListNumbers1 = rd.randint(1,10000)
```

How would i  get the 50 highest numbers from ListNumbers1 and append to list1?

Comment: `ListNumbers1` is not a list

Comment: you overwrite `ListNumbers1` in your loop over and over. Disregarding that: `List1 += sorted(ListNumbers1[-50:])` You are better off if you just use a list comprehension:  `sorted([rd.randint(1,10000) for j in range(1000)])`

Comment: What about repeated numbers?  Or do you want them to be 50 unique numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
List1.extend(sorted(ListNumbers1)[-50:])
```

Comment: i try that and it said that the int wasnt iterable

Comment: @eunason You need to fix your assignment in your for loop. `ListNumbers1 = rd.randint(1,10000)` should be `ListNumbers1.append(rd.randint(1,10000))`

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the same value over and over in your loop, destroying your list in the process. Use `append`...

Better: create a list comprehension of the numbers, then use `heapq.nlargest` to directly get the 50 highest numbers:

```
import random as rd
import heapq

highest_50 = heapq.nlargest(50,[rd.randint(1,10000) for _ in range(1000)])

print(highest_50)
```

a result:

```
[9994, 9983, 9983, 9968, 9934, 9925, 9913, 9912, 9909, 9909, 9902, 9889, 9884, 9880, 9811, 9794, 9793, 9792, 9765, 9756, 9750, 9748, 9738, 9737, 9709, 9707, 9704, 9700, 9691, 9686, 9635, 9618, 9617, 9605, 9604, 9593, 9586, 9584, 9573, 9569, 9569, 9557, 9531, 9528, 9522, 9438, 9438, 9431, 9402, 9400]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I have a more efficient solution:

```
from random import randint
import heapq

# create a list of 1000 random numbers
# take the negative, so the min heap does what we want
dataset = [-randint(1, 10000) for _ in range(1000)]

# O(n) function to impose the heap invariant
heapq.heapify(dataset)

# sorting is O(n log n)
# extracting from a heap is log n per item
# therefore taking the 50 biggest is much more efficent if
# we use a heap to extract only the ones we need
top50 = [-heapq.heappop(dataset) for _ in range(50)]

print top50
```

This is a faster solution because the 50 you want to extract is much less than the 1000 total input size. I renamed the variables, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: isn't that the same as `heapq.nlargest()` ?

Comment: Probably. I don't know how that one is implemented, but we can follow this and know the algorithmic performance guarantees. Also, I didn't know about nlargest, but it probably is an optimized builtin and thus may run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Like that (notice how assigning random number is fixed):

```
import random as rd

ListNumbers1 = []
List1 = []


for j in range(1000):
    ListNumbers1.append(rd.randint(1,10000)) # fix: append each random element

ListNumbers1.sort()         # sort the list, ascending order
List1 = ListNumbers1[-50:]  # get last 50 elements of the list and assign it to List1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random as rd
List1 = sorted([rd.randint(1,10000) for j in range(1000)])[-50:]
```

Slice the last 50 elements of a sorted list comprehension, then you don't need `ListNumbers1`

Comment: Can you include some explanation/context for this?

Comment: there you go @EJoshuaS

Answer (score 0):

To search for the n biggest numbers in a list you need two procedures: one to find the biggest, the other to extract the n biggest.
You could also sort the list and take the n first, but this is not my approach because I needed to keep the original list and study it as is. For example, you could also know the offsets of each chosen number, which could be useful in some case.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
def n_biggest(lis,howmany):

    #this function returns the biggest of a list with its offset
    def biggest_in_list(lis):
        n=0
        biggest=0
        offset=0
        for item in lis:
            n=n+1
            if (item>biggest):
                biggest=item
                offset=n-1
        return[biggest,offset]

    #now this is the part where we create the descending list
    image=lis#the use of an image will prevent finding twice the same number
    result_list=[]
    if len(lis)<howmany:#this will prevent errors if list is too small
        howmany=len(lis)
    for i in range(howmany):
        find1=biggest_in_list(image)
        result_list.append(find1[0])
        image.pop(find1[1])
    return result_list

print n_biggest([5,4,6,10,233,422],3)#this line was for testing the above
```

Hope this helps,
Regards,